# jQuery autohide element after 5 seconds, if there is no mouse over

Tags: jquery

I am writing a shopping cart effect. When user add the product to shopping cart, the floating cart appears and hide in 5 seconds.

```
$("#cart").show().delay(5000).hide();
```

the problem is what if the user want to change something like quantity and the mouse is over the cart, obviously I don't want the cart to disappear when user mouse is over the cart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two main ways to approach this

Using a clearTimeout if the user mouses onto the item to stop the hide.

```
var countdown;

$("#cart").show().hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
})

countdown = setTimeout(function() {
$('#cart').hide();
}, 5000);
```

Or

Using a boolean to decide whether or not to do the hide

```
mouseOver = false;
$("#cart").show(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!mouseOver)
       $('#cart').hide();
   }, 5000)).hover(function() {
    mouseOver = true;
};
```

You could also (this makes the item fade unless they move the mouse over the item every 5 seconds):

```
var countdown;

$("#cart").show(resetCountdown).mousemove(resetCountdown);

function resetCountdown() {
   clearTimeout(countdown);
   countdown = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#cart').hide();
   }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean value set to false, and then when you mouse over set it to true. Meanwhile, have a function defined using setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
if (!mybool)
$('#cart').hide();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cart").show();
   $("#cart").delay(5000).hide();
});
```

or you can also edit like

```
$("#cart").hide('5000');
```